# Writing a functions that removes an array and adds to the list

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm currently learning Javascript at freecodecamp and am at the point where I'm learning about functions.

I'm on a task that is asking me to right a type of `queue` that will removed the first item from the array, and replace it with another (at the end of the array).

Here's what I have so far:

```
function nextInLine(arr, item) {
  // Your code here
  array = [];
  array.shift(arr);
  array.push(item);
  return arr;  // Change this line
}

// Test Setup
var testArr = [1,2,3,4,5];

// Display Code
console.log("Before: " + JSON.stringify(testArr));
console.log(nextInLine(testArr, 6)); // Modify this line to test
console.log("After: " + JSON.stringify(testArr));
```

However when run with the test setup it out puts:

> Before: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>
> After: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

I'm confused as all get out.. How would I accomplish this task?

Actual task:

> In Computer Science a queue is an abstract Data Structure where items are kept in order. New items can be added at the back of the queue and old items are taken off from the front of the queue.
>
> Write a function nextInLine which takes an array (arr) and a number (item) as arguments. Add the number to the end of the array, then remove the first element of array. The nextInLine function should then return the element that was removed.

Comment: Get rid of `array = [];` and use `arr` in the function since that's the one you want to modify. `arr.shift(); arr.push(item)`

Comment: The `nextInLine` function is modifying a local `array`, not the original `arr`, so the original `testArr` is unchanged when you write it to the console.

Comment: Okay so me creating a local `array` is what's throwing it off I would want to do what @squint said and modify the original `arr`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr You're using `Array.prototype.shift` and `Array.prototype.push` wrong.

`shift` removes the first item from an array and **returns that item.** Instead of

```
array = [];
array.shift(arr);
```

You want to do

```
var firstItem = arr.shift();
```

`push` adds an item to the end of an array. You want to mutate the original array object *in place*, so you want to do

```
arr.push(item);
```

Then return the first item

```
return firstItem;
```

This gives you the following function:

```
function nextInLine(arr, item) {
  arr.push(item);
  var firstItem = arr.shift(arr);
  return firstItem;
}
```

Comment: I understand! However when run with an empty array (`nextInLine([], 1)` for example) this doesn't output the correct information.

Comment: If it's an empty array, there's no elements to return

Comment: I made an edit, you need to simply reverse the operations `push` and `shift`

Comment: This: `nextInLine([], 1)` should return `1`

Comment: Okay that did it, so why did I need to switch the two around? Why wouldn't it work the same way, either way?

Comment: Because when you do `shift` before `push`, the array is empty when the `shift` operation is run, so there are no elements to pull off. When you `push` first, the item you pushed is there when `shift` is run, so there are items to pull out.

Comment: Awh okay, that makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to modify the passed array then you should run all the commands on it.

```
function nextInLine(arr, item) {
  // Your code here
  arr.shift();
  arr.push(item);
  return arr;  // this line is only required if you want to assign to a new array at the same time
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function nextInLine(arr, item) 
{ 
    // Your code here arr.push(item); 
    return item = arr.shift(); 
    // return item; 
    // Change this line 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
function nextInLine(arr, item) {
 arr.push(item);
 item = arr.shift();
 return item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function nextInLine(arr, item) {

    // Your code here

    var queue = arr.push(item);
    var removeItem = arr.shift();

    return removeItem;  // Change this line
}

// Test Setup

var testArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// Display Code

console.log("Before: " + JSON.stringify(testArr));
console.log(nextInLine(testArr, 6));
// Modify this line to test

console.log("After: " + JSON.stringify(testArr));
```

Explanation:

To add the number at the end of the array, use `.push()`

To remove the first element, use `.shift()`

To return the element that was removed, use `return removeItem` and after setup the var with the `.shift()` method.